# jsPDF consult extenal server to create PDF or PDF is created only in the client side?

Tags: jspdf

I am using jsPDF to generate a PDF, I want to know if jsPDF generate PDF in the client side or consult any external server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jspdf` is able to work completely client-side in the browser. Of course, if You need to include inside Your PDF some resources other than plain text, for example images, You may need first to download them. If all Your resources are available in the browser cache or inside the `localstorage`, `jspdf` can also work offline.